# How do I disable phone ringing from my Tile?

Tags: bluetooth, ios, tile

When a Tile tracker is paired with a phone, double tapping a button on the Tile will make the phone ring. This happens [even if the phone is on silent mode](https://support.thetileapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/207274527-Use-Tile-to-Ring-your-Phone). I’ve accidentally rung my iPhone at work multiple times, disturbing the people around me.

I want to leave the Tile paired to my phone so I can track my personal belongings, but I don’t want my phone to ring. Hiding my phone in the Tile app had no effect.

How can I disable the option to ring my phone from a Tile?

Comment: This feature is available on Android. Tested July 2019 on Android version 9.

Comment: @John Are the steps to disable *Find Your Phone* the same as iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For iOS users, an option to disable "*Find Your Phone*" was added in Tile [v2.28.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzwnV.png).**

- Open the Tile device list
- Press `...` on a tile and select *Edit Tile Details*
- Under *Actions*, unselect the option for *Find Your Phone*

  [image]

According to [a comment by Geoff](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/how-do-i-disable-phone-ringing-from-my-tile/2877#comment11847_2877), this feature was also added to Android sometime prior to May 4, 2021